# separate a DAG into a forest of level-ordered topological sorted subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG where an edge represents a dependency between two nodes and a node represents a task that is to be executed on a machine. There are multiple machines. For each (task,machine) pair there is an estimated runtime.
Now, I would like to separate this DAG into a forest so that each subgraph in the forest represents itself a "complete" DAG and is represented by a topological level ordered sorting. By "complete" I mean that the subgraph starting from any root node has exactly all the paths that it has in the original DAG.
I am given an unordered `List<Task> tasks` where `Task` is a class that represents a task node in the DAG. Every Task has a List of all its parents and a List of all its children.
How I would naively go about: iterate over all the nodes v, do a dfs to get the subgraph rooted at v, in each iteration check if one can merge two subgraphs because they have a common parent.
Can this be done faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the graph into components using a depth-first search which traverses both child and parent links. Then you can do a topological sort on each component. Both algorithms are O(N+E) (for N nodes and E edges); that could be O(N²) but for typical dependency graphs where the number of dependencies is generally small, it's probably closer to O(N).

Comment: Could you elaborate how to get from the obtained subgraphs of parent and child nodes to the forest of graphs that each have exactly all paths found in the original graphs? i.e. the forest of isolated DAGs? Its probably obvious but I don't see it :/

Comment: @max: the basic discovery algorithm is something like `for task in tasklist: if task not yet seen: visit(task)`  where visit(task) would be `for relative in task.children+task.parents: if relative not yet seen: visit relative`. To create the subgraphs, we just make a tiny change: in the conditional of the outer loop, we create a new subgraph list, which we pass into visit as a second argument. And we modify `visit`: before it starts the loop, it adds the current node (its first argument) to the subgraph list (its second argument). It simply passes the subgraph list on in the recursive call.

Comment: Since we don't actually change the nodes, there's no need to change the edges between nodes. All we do is partition the original list into a list of subgraph lists.

Comment: Oh I think I got it - yeah its actually not so hard to see thanks.